# My projectiles wont collide with my enemies in a 2D side scrolling Unity project?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collision

As the title suggests, I've literally just started learning Unity recently and I'm practising by making a side scrolling shooter. I've been following a Udemy course about it and (to my knowledge) I've been following the tutor's instructions to the letter, but at the point where he tests his and it works fine, by projectiles go straight through my enemies.

I'm a bit stumped at this point and so I thought I'd post here to see what you guys thought. I bet it's something really simple I've not done.

Please see my projectile code below:

```
using UnityEngine; using System.Collections;

public class DestroyEnemyAndProjectile : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject WhiteExplosion;
public GameObject OrangeExplosion;

void Start()
{

}


void Update()
{

}

void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D tempCollision)
{
    if (tempCollision.gameObject.tag == "Collision")
    {
        spawnParticles(tempCollision.transform.position);

        Destroy(tempCollision.gameObject);
    }

}

void spawnParticles(Vector2 tempPosition)
{
    Instantiate(WhiteExplosion, tempPosition, Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(OrangeExplosion, tempPosition, Quaternion.identity);
}
}
```

Thanks for your help!

I did post a question to them which got a response, they suggested that perhaps the projectile is going too fast and check there was a Rigidbody 2D attached - both of which were already collect

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the object you're colliding with has the tag "Collision", with the same capitalisation. 
If it's not, you can do this by:

```
1. Selecting the GameObject to be collided with
2. In the top-right, select the Tag property
3. Add tag, click the plus and type in "Collision"
4. Select the GameObject again, and select the "Collision" tag from the Tag property dropdown
```

Otherwise, if that's not the issue. Make sure the projectile has a type of Collider2D component, and that the projectile, or the object being collided with, has a Rigidbody2D.

Comment: Things that you should check, in order for collision to work:

Answer (score 0):

First I would like to know what the behaviour of this script curently is. Is the collision method being called, and the projectile goes through the enemy anyway? Or the collision method is not being called at all?

That being said, these are things that you should check in order for collision to work:

- Make sure that the projectile and the enemy have Collider2D components attached to them.
- Make sure that the projectile and/or the enemy (at least one of them must) have a Rigidbody2D attached to it.
- Make sure that the layer of the projectiles and the layer of the enemies are set to collide in the collision matrix (You can find the collision matrix in Edit->ProjectSettings->Physics)
- Make sure that the enemy GameObject has its tag set to "Collision".

P.S: Welcome to Unity where issues like this are, in fact, usually caused by something super simple that you probably missed.